# Is there a way to change the background color of an image using Pillow in Python without affecting the object itself?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When I tried it, it affected all parts of my image but what I want is just the background to be changed from white to yellow and parts of the cat shouldn't be affected. Attached is my code. I used Pillow in Visual Studio Code for Mac.

Code-https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX4YH.png

Image of cat-https://all-free-download.com/free-photos/download/cat_feline_cats_eye_215231.html
I don't know how to show the image that I want but the white background in the cat image should be yellow without affecting the cat itself and its whiskers or face

Comment: Pls share code (in a form that can be copy pasted) and the result you are seeing and what you would expect to see

Comment: Hello I have edited it, kindly check

Comment: The hard part is splitting the background from the rest of the image.

Comment: So do you know how to do it? Because whenever I try, it's affecting the image itself.